# Overwrite char (or std::string) array positions with SWIG?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, char, swig

I was able to write a void function in C/C++, and wrap to Python/Numpy with SWIG `(int* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1)`, that receives a `int* vector` as parameter, do some math on this vector, and overwrite the results on the same vector, and this result was available inside Python's object. Like follows:

```
    extern "C" void soma_aloc(int* vetor, int tamanho)
    {
       int m = 0;
       int* ponteiro = new int[tamanho];

       for(m = 0; m < tamanho; m++)
       {           
          ponteiro[m] = vetor[m];
       };

       for(m = 0; m < tamanho; m++)
       {
          ponteiro[m] = ponteiro[m] * 10;
       };

       for(m = 0; m < tamanho; m++)
       {
          vetor[m] = ponteiro[m];
       };

       delete [] ponteiro; 
       };
```

This was a test to learn how to wrap pointers to int and double arrays with SWIG using the `typemaps (DATA_TYPE* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1)` and `(DATA_TYPE* INPLACE_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2)`, and worked well.

But the problem is, I've tried the same idea with char/string Numpy vectors (like a vector `vec1 = numpy.array(['a','a','a'])` or `numpy.array(['a','a','a'],dtype=str)`, and change each position to be like `(['b','b','b'])`, but Python shows `in method 'vector_char2D', argument 1 of type 'char *'`. It's possible to do the same with char/string?

```
    .cpp:

    extern "C" void vetor_char2D(char* vetorchar, int tamanho_vetor)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < tamanho_vetor; i++)
       {
           vetorchar[i] = 'b';
       };
    };

    .i:

    %module testestring

    %include stl.i
    %include std_string.i

    %{

  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  //#include <string.h>
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>

  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
      #include "testestring.hpp"

    %}

    %include "numpy.i"

    %init %{
     import_array();
    %}

    %apply (char* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(char* vetorchar, int tamanho_vetor)}
    %include "testestring.hpp" (just the header of the above function vetor_char2D)
    %clear (char* vetorchar, int tamanho_vetor);
```

I have very litthe experience with SWIG. It's possible to do this with `char*`, `char**` and/or `std::string*/std::string**` ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use std::vector:

```
void vetor_char2D(std::vector<std::string>& vetorchar)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < vetorchar.size(); i++)
       vetorchar[i] = "b";
};
```

which indicates clearly that the vector can be modified, and strings within it can be modified, and the SWIG typemaps for STL vectors and strings will work nicely. Note the double rather than single quote for string; Python only has strings no chars so it doesn't matter. You can also make it work with char* etc but it is rarely worth the effort, lot easier to use above. If you don't want to change the source, you can include the above as a wrapper in the .i file via an %inline directive.

Note you should not need the extern C qualifier. And you should use the `#include <string>` not string.h.

Comment: Thanks buddy! Now it's working! I'm using with this templates inside .i file:

%template(IntVector) std::vector<int>;
%template(DoubleVector) std::vector<double>;
%template(StringVector) std::vector<std::string>;
%template(ConstCharVector) std::vector<const char*>;

And inside Python, I build the properly objects with (name of the module).StringVector(length).

Question: Do I need to deallocate those vectors inside Python?

Comment: @eldiegon No you don't because swig copies the strings between the two layers, there is no mem to manage.

Comment: @eldiegon Great. Note that the way to thank people is to vote up the answers and comments you find useful, and to mark *the* most useful/correct/helpful answer (checkmark).